# Delete statement sending "Only AEQuery is supported" error

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am performing a simple `delete from` statement to remove about 11k rows of data in our Hadoop Hive data warehouse.

```
DELETE FROM db.table_name
WHERE column='foo';
```

My where statement filters out what to keep and what not to keep, but the error back is

```
Only AEQuery is supported. [SQL State=error]
```

I cannot figure out how the delete statement is wrong. I have been able to run a `delete from` statement in the past on the same database (but a different schema). Is there a permissions issue? How can I find out?

Comment: Check there will be difference with table definition ..

Comment: add the create table command.  make sure that you have the following properties https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511769/crud-operations-in-hive/44513773#44513773